# C bitwise operations relevant bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find exactly what I want.

I have the current value of a byte:

> 00110001  A

And I have to write another value:

> 10001001  B

but in the 2nd byte only some bits
are relevant. The relevant bits
are the ones with a one in this bit

> 11000000  C

The final byte will be B on the bits where C==1 and A on the bits where C==0.
How can I do that with no if statements?

The answer is D 10110001

Comment: `if` is not a loop, it's kind of a branching statement. Anyway, are you looking for the [bitwise AND operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_AND_.22.26.22)?

Comment: There are no such thing as "if loops". You probably mean "if statements".

Comment: @JonathonReinhart may be he means: with no if and loop

Comment: Thank you all for your quick correct answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mask and combine:

```
finalByte = (B & C) | (A & ~C);
```

To break down how it works - the result of `B & C` is a byte containing all of the bits of `B` where bits of `C` are set (a normal masking operation).  `A & ~C` yields a byte with all of the bits of `A` where bits of `C` are cleared - hence the `~` complement operation.  The `|` combines the two into the final byte you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

```
(B & C) | (A & ~C)
```

The first expression keeps only the bits of `B` where `C` is set; the second keeps only the bits of `A` where `C` is *not* set; and the logical or combines those two bit-sets to give the result you want.